# Why in the Three.js PointerLockControls source does the yawObject position get forced to a maximum of 10?

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I am working on a basic Demo FPS engine and I am using the PointerLockControls example found in the Three.js source here:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/PointerLockControls.js

```
/**
 * @author mrdoob / http://mrdoob.com/
 */

THREE.PointerLockControls = function ( camera ) {

    var scope = this;

    camera.rotation.set( 0, 0, 0 );

    var pitchObject = new THREE.Object3D();
    pitchObject.add( camera );

    var yawObject = new THREE.Object3D();
    yawObject.position.y = 10;
    yawObject.add( pitchObject );

    var moveForward = false;
    var moveBackward = false;
    var moveLeft = false;
    var moveRight = false;

    var isOnObject = false;
    var canJump = false;

    var velocity = new THREE.Vector3();

    var PI_2 = Math.PI / 2;

    var onMouseMove = function ( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        var movementX = event.movementX || event.mozMovementX || event.webkitMovementX || 0;
        var movementY = event.movementY || event.mozMovementY || event.webkitMovementY || 0;

        yawObject.rotation.y -= movementX * 0.002;
        pitchObject.rotation.x -= movementY * 0.002;

        pitchObject.rotation.x = Math.max( - PI_2, Math.min( PI_2, pitchObject.rotation.x ) );

    };

    var onKeyDown = function ( event ) {

        switch ( event.keyCode ) {

            case 38: // up
            case 87: // w
                moveForward = true;
                break;

            case 37: // left
            case 65: // a
                moveLeft = true; break;

            case 40: // down
            case 83: // s
                moveBackward = true;
                break;

            case 39: // right
            case 68: // d
                moveRight = true;
                break;

            case 32: // space
                if ( canJump === true ) velocity.y += 10;
                canJump = false;
                break;

        }

    };

    var onKeyUp = function ( event ) {

        switch( event.keyCode ) {

            case 38: // up
            case 87: // w
                moveForward = false;
                break;

            case 37: // left
            case 65: // a
                moveLeft = false;
                break;

            case 40: // down
            case 83: // s
                moveBackward = false;
                break;

            case 39: // right
            case 68: // d
                moveRight = false;
                break;

        }

    };

    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onKeyUp, false );

    this.enabled = false;

    this.getObject = function () {

        return yawObject;

    };

    this.isOnObject = function ( boolean ) {

        isOnObject = boolean;
        canJump = boolean;

    };

    this.getDirection = function() {

        // assumes the camera itself is not rotated

        var direction = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 );
        var rotation = new THREE.Euler( 0, 0, 0, "YXZ" );

        return function( v ) {

            rotation.set( pitchObject.rotation.x, yawObject.rotation.y, 0 );

            v.copy( direction ).applyEuler( rotation );

            return v;

        }

    }();

    this.update = function ( delta ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        delta *= 0.1;

        velocity.x += ( - velocity.x ) * 0.08 * delta;
        velocity.z += ( - velocity.z ) * 0.08 * delta;

        velocity.y -= 0.25 * delta;

        if ( moveForward ) velocity.z -= 0.12 * delta;
        if ( moveBackward ) velocity.z += 0.12 * delta;

        if ( moveLeft ) velocity.x -= 0.12 * delta;
        if ( moveRight ) velocity.x += 0.12 * delta;

        if ( isOnObject === true ) {

            velocity.y = Math.max( 0, velocity.y );

        }

        yawObject.translateX( velocity.x );
        yawObject.translateY( velocity.y ); 
        yawObject.translateZ( velocity.z );

        if ( yawObject.position.y < 10 ) {

            velocity.y = 0;
            yawObject.position.y = 10;

            canJump = true;

        }

    };

};
```

As I am trying to learn exactly how it works, I am attempting to understand the main parts of the code, however there is one part of the source I do not understand, and that part is this:

(Line 169 of the source linked above)

```
if ( yawObject.position.y < 10 ) {
    velocity.y = 0;
    yawObject.position.y = 10;
    canJump = true;
}
```

I really don't understand what this part of the code is for. I found if I remove it, the player's camera will spin out of control. I also found if I change the number from 10 it seems to make no difference. So my question is; what is this code for, and what will changing that number do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So upon further playing around. I have realized that this is (very obviously) just a check to ensure the player stays above the ground. The change between 10 and 0 appeared to do nothing, but it was actually just a very tiny change in camera height (barely noticeable). The swaying camera appearance that occurred when the lines were removed, was simply just the terrain flying past as you fell through the floor.

Comment: Hi :) yawObject is the player, but i don't understand exactly the purpose of pitchObject... Have you found what is this for ?